# Filter Task List with buttons (with metod filter)

Tags: javascript, filter, methods, tasklist

I need to filter with this method the tasks that have been completed, those that are not completed and that all appear, interacting with the three buttons; to be able to filter these tasks with these filters and that only the correct ones come out, it is the only functionality that my task list lacks.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  let id = 0;
  let text = "";
  let alert = document.querySelector(".alert");
  let alertGreen = document.querySelector(".alert-green");
  let close = alert.firstElementChild;
  let input = document.querySelector("#task");
  let arrow = document.querySelector(".arrow");
  let done = document.querySelectorAll(".fa-circle-check");
  let trash = document.querySelectorAll(".fa-trash");
  let edit = document.querySelectorAll(".fa-pencil");
  let task = document.querySelectorAll(".task");
  let btnAll = document.querySelector(".btn");
  let btnToDo = btnAll.nextElementSibling;
  let btnDone = btnToDo.nextElementSibling;
  let taskArray = [].slice.call(task);
  console.log(taskArray);



  close.addEventListener("click", () => {
    alert.classList.add("dismissible");
  });
  input.addEventListener("focus", () => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
      // console.log(event.code);
      if (event.code == "Enter" || event.code == "NumpadEnter") {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  });
  //Alert Verde con temporizador
  arrow.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    if (input.value.trim() !== "") {
      alertGreen.classList.remove("dismissible");
      setTimeout(() => {
        alertGreen.classList.add("dismissible");
      }, 5000);
    }
    if (input.value.trim() == "") {
      //Trim elimina los espacios al inicio y al final del string
      // console.log("Empty");
      event.preventDefault();
      input.value = "";
      alert.classList.remove("class", "dismissible");
    } else {
      let text = input.value;
      input.value = "";
      id =
        Number(document.querySelector("tbody")?.lastElementChild?.id) + 1 || 0;
      //?? operador condicional?? por si no existe o está vacío

      //Creando una nueva fila

      document.querySelector("tbody").appendChild(generateRow(id, text));
      if (!alert.classList.contains("dismissible")) {
        alert.classList.add("dismissible");
      }
    }
  });
  done.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      deleteTask(e);
    });
  });
  trash.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      removeRow(e, false);
    });
  });
  edit.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      editTask(e, false);
    });
  });
  task.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("focus", (e) => {
      editTask(e, true);
    });
  });
});

// Funciones para refactorizar el código
const generateRow = (id, text) => {
  let newRow = document.createElement("tr");
  newRow.setAttribute("id", id);
  newRow.innerHTML = `
          <td>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check fa-2x"></i>
          <span class="task" contenteditable="true"> ${text} </span>
          </td>
          <td>
          <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-pencil fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
          </span>
          </td>
          <td>
          <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-trash fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
          </span>
          </td>
          `;
  newRow.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    deleteTask(e);
  });
  newRow.firstElementChild.lastElementChild.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    editTask(e, true);
  });
  newRow.lastElementChild.firstElementChild.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    removeRow(e, false);
  });
  newRow.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild.addEventListener(
    "click",
    (e) => {
      editTask(e, false);
    }
  );

  return newRow;
};
const deleteTask = (e) => {
  let task = e.target.nextElementSibling;
  text = task.innerHTML;
  if (text.includes("<del>")) {
    task.innerHTML = task.firstElementChild.textContent;
    task.setAttribute("data-completed", "false");
  } else {
    task.innerHTML = `<del>${text}</del>`;
    task.setAttribute("data-completed", "true");
  }
};
const removeRow = (e, editing) => {
  if (editing) {
    e.target.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
  } else {
    e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
  }
};
const editTask = (e, onFocus) => {
  let editable = e;
  if (onFocus) {
    e.target.classList.add("editable");
    document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
      if (e.code == "Escape") {
        editable.target.classList.remove("editable");
        // Elimina el puntero del foco
        editable.target.blur();
        if (editable.target.textContent.trim() == "") {
          removeRow(editable, true);
        }
      }
    });
    editable.target.addEventListener("blur", () => {
      editable.target.classList.remove("editable");
      if (editable.target.textContent.trim() == "") {
        removeRow(editable, true);
      }
    });
  } else {
    let editable =
      e.target.parentNode.parentNode.previousElementSibling.lastElementChild;
    editable.classList.add("editable");
    editable.focus();
  }
};
```

```css
:root {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  --blue: #0d6efd;
  --indigo: #6610f2;
  --purple: #6f42c1;
  --pink: #d63384;
  --red: #dc3545;
  --orange: #fd7e14;
  --yellow: #ffc107;
  --green: #198754;
  --teal: #20c997;
  --cyan: #0dcaf0;
  --dark: #292a2b;
  --black: #000;
  --color1: #e63946;
  --color2: #f1faee;
  --color3: #a8dadc;
  --color4: #457b9d;
  --color5: #1d3557;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
::before,
::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  outline: 0 none;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3.9rem;
  font-family: "Smooch Sans", sans-serif;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2.25rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  background-color: var(--color3);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, var(--color2), var(--color3));
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.btn-group {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #3b71ca;
  color: #fff;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  padding: 0.625rem 1.5rem 0.5rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0.125rem solid transparent;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.btn:hover {
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 9px -4px var(--dark);
  background-color: #2c68ca;
}

.btn-group>.btn:not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle) {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.btn-group>.btn-group:not(:first-child)>.btn,
.btn-group>.btn:nth-child(n + 3),
.btn-group> :not(.btn-check)+.btn {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.btn-group>.btn-group:not(:first-child)>.btn,
.btn-group>.btn:nth-child(n + 3),
.btn-group> :not(.btn-check)+.btn {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.btn-group>.btn-group:not(:first-child),
.btn-group>.btn:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: -0.325rem;
}

.main {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 2em;
  margin: 10% auto;
  background-color: white;
}

.main .container {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.main form {
  width: 100%;
}

.main label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main label div {
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: var(--blue);
  min-height: 60px;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.3rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.3rem;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.main label div:hover {
  background-color: #0b5ed7;
}

.main label div .fa-solid {
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.main label div .fa-solid:hover {
  transform: translateX(10px);
}

.main input {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #bee5e3;
  padding: 0.5em;
  min-height: 60px;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  border-top-left-radius: 0.3rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.3rem;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.main input::placeholder {
  color: var(--dark);
}

.main input:focus {
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgba(13, 110, 253, 0.25);
  z-index: 2;
}

.main .alert {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: var(--pink);
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.main .alert .fa-square-xmark {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.main .alert .fa-square-xmark:hover {
  color: var(--dark);
}

.main .alert-green {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: var(--green);
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.main .alert-green .fa-square-check {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.main .alert-green .fa-square-check:hover {
  color: var(--dark);
}

.main table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  margin: 2em auto;
}

.main tr {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.main tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.main th {
  background-color: #2980d9;
  padding: 0.5em;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.main th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 0.3rem;
}

.main th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 0.3rem;
}

.main td {
  font-family: "Fredoka", sans-serif;
  padding: 0.8em;
}

.main td:first-child {
  width: 70%;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.main td:nth-child(2),
.main td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 15%;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.main table .fa-2x {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  color: var(--yellow);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.main table .fa-2x:hover {
  color: #ffca2c;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.main table td:nth-child(3) .fa-2x {
  color: #dc3545;
}

.main table td:nth-child(3) .fa-2x:hover {
  color: #bb2d3b;
}

.main table .fa-circle-check {
  color: var(--green);
  margin-right: 15px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.main table .fa-circle-check:hover {
  color: var(--teal);
}

.main table .editable {
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.3em;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  margin-top: 0.3em;
}

.main .dismissible {
  opacity: 0 !important;
  height: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Task-List</title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fredoka:wght@400;700&family=Lato:wght@100;400;700&family=Smooch+Sans:wght@100;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/69ea5f183b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body class="">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="nav">
      <h1>Task List </h1>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
        <button type="button" class="btn">All</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn">To Do</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn">Done</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="alert dismissible">
      Please, enter some text.
      <i class="fa-solid fa-square-xmark"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="alert-green dismissible">
      Task added successfully.
      <i class="fa-solid fa-square-check"></i>
    </div>
    <form name="new-task">
      <label for="task">
          <input
            type="text"
            name="task"
            id="task"
            placeholder="Add a new task"
          />
          <div class="arrow"><i class="fa-solid fa-right-long fa-2xl"></i></div>
        </label>
    </form>
    <div class="container">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Don't forget To Do This</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr id="0">
            <td>
              <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check fa-2x"></i>
              <span class="task" contenteditable="true" data-completed="false"> Learn HTML! </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                  <i class="fa-solid fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
                  <i class="fa-solid fa-pencil fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                  <i class="fa-solid fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
                  <i class="fa-solid fa-trash fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="1">
            <td>
              <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check fa-2x"></i>
              <span class="task" contenteditable="true" data-completed="true"><del>CSS</del></span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                  <i class="fa-solid fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
                  <i class="fa-solid fa-pencil fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                  <i class="fa-solid fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
                  <i class="fa-solid fa-trash fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: *"I need this"* and posting hundreds of lines of code is not helpful. Help us to help you, determine your specific issue, highlight the specific part of the code you tried. Read: [ask] and since you haven't, take a [tour].

Comment: Sorry for phrasing the question, it's my first time.
I thought the complete code was necessary to put in context, I'll keep it in mind for the next one.

Comment: What is necessary is a [mcve]. And an explanation of the issue you have. In your current code you have no actual issues. Since this is not a coding service website, you should specific what you tried and where/what is the issue you encountered.

Answer (score 1):

Next time please attach a copy of a task object.

You can use filter() function like this :

```
function filterTasksCompleted(tasks) {
   return tasks.filter(task => task.isComplete); //return array with only tasks which have isComplete = true key.
}
```